# How to run Rebol script on Linux 64-bit

Tags: linux, x86-64, rebol

I can not run this sample Rebol script

```
REBOL []
alert
"Hello World"
```

on Debian 10 Linux 64-bit OS.

The script is from the [official Rebol tutorial](http://www.rebol.com/docs/quick-start3.html).

I'm trying to run it using this command from console:

```
$ rebol hi
```

but it fails with error message

```
Script: "Untitled" (none)
** Script Error: alert has no value
** Near: alert "Hello World"
```

I use [the latest available build](http://www.rebol.com/downloads.html) for Linux x86-64 from the official Rebol site.

```
REBOL/Core 2.7.8.4.10 (23-Jan-2016)
Copyright 2016 REBOL Technologies
```

How to run the script?

Does Rebol support GUI on Linux?

I've found in the documentation Rebol runs on all mainstream platforms:

> REBOL is cross-platform.
>   A program written on Windows runs equally well on Linux, BSD, OS X, and many other platforms... with no changes necessary.

Source: http://www.rebol.com/what-rebol.html

But I tried this script and also an Bookmarks example with `layout` dialect and they both fail with `has no value` error.

I also tried to add `.r` extension to the script but it seems it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Rebol has two versions: core and 
[view](http://www.rebol.com/download-view.html). And core version does not has graphics support. But view version does not support 64-bit Linux directly now. No 64-bit build exists, but there's 32-bit build.

To run an alert example using 32-bit build of Rebol View one may need to install required 32-bit libraries (and if I remember correctly first somehow enable 32-bit arch support on 64-bit linux):

On my Debian 10 machine I needed `libx11.so.6` and some other X11 related libs:

```
$ sudo apt install libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxt6:i386 libxaw7:i386 libfreetype6:i386
```

Now the script can be run by command such as:

```
$ rebol hi.r
```